# Does nodejs have a working diff library or algorithm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, diff

I'm looking for a javascript diff algorithm implementation or library, which has been tested on and works with arbitrary utf8 text files.

All of the ones I found so far (say for example, http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/) fail on corner cases

(Try using a file which contains the string `'__proto__'` in my example library.)

Comment: http://toolbox.no.de/search?q=diff

Comment: DeaDEnD please post that as teh answer, it solved my problems.

Comment: there are diff tools written for unix, use them

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe this will help you — [jsdiff](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff)

Comment: Upstream is ahead again, so I updated the link. I suspect at the time you posted this that upstream had fallen behind. Here's the one it was linked to previously: https://github.com/NV/jsdiff

Answer (score 6):

I'm a fan of [google diff match patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/). You can try out an example [here](http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html).

There are different cleanup option to tweak the level of commonality between the diffs. I don't like the semantic cleanup option as I find it's too aggressive, but the efficiency cleanup with a value of 10 works well for me.

Comment: I like this one because it's available in Java, JavaScript, Dart, C++, C#, Objective C, Lua and Python. Regardless of language, each library features the same API and the same functionality.

Answer (score 3):

There is an diff algorithm implementation that I wrote with javascript in the following page.

https://github.com/cubicdaiya/onp

This runs with node.js. Forthermore there is a C++ addon version for node.js in following page.

https://github.com/cubicdaiya/node-dtl

You can install this with npm.

$ npm install -g dtl

Answer (score 2):

There is also adiff which is a diff/patch library written in Javascript.

https://github.com/dominictarr/adiff

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the JavaScript library [wikEd diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Cacycle/diff). It has Unicode and multilingual support. It also detects and highlights block moves and is word/character based. You can also use the [online too/demo](http://cacycle.altervista.org/wikEd-diff-tool.html) for testing different settings and to look at the internal data structures. The library's code is fully commented.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, somewhere inside of the [Mocha test tool](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) - see [TJ Holowaychuk's blog post about it](http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/18574009869/mocha-string-diffs).